# how to access to anchor in specific class? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, frontend

```
 <p class="submit" align="center"><a href="email.html"> Create an account</p>
 <p class="forgot" align="center"><a href="login.html"> Already have an account? </p>
```

Since there are two different anchor, (which is email.html and login.html) I want to use a different color for each anchor. However, I am not sure how to access to anchor in specific class.
Suppose I want to change the color email.html to white, then is it something like

```
 submit a {
    color:white;
   }
```

?

Answer (score 0):

add dot first:

```
    .submit a {
    color:white;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I was struggling for like 30 min because of this :)